# How to maintain rounded corner of Rect when scaling in fabric js

Tags: javascript, rounding, fabricjs, rect

I am using fabric js version 1.7.22.

Original Object:

[image]

Current result :

[image]

Expected result :

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to watch for `scaling` events and reset the Rect's scale to 1, modifying its `width` and `height` instead:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'blue',
  rx: 10,
  ry: 10,
  objectCaching: false,
})

rect.on('scaling', function() {
  this.set({
    width: this.width * this.scaleX,
    height: this.height * this.scaleY,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1
  })
})

canvas.add(rect).renderAll()
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
```

Comment: how it can be done via recalculate rx and ry of Rect ?

Answer (score 0):

To scale and recalculate `rx` and `ry` you can do something like this:

```js
this.canvas.on("object:scaling", function() {
  this.set({
    rx: 10 * (1 / this.scaleX),
    ry: 10 * (1 / this.scaleY)
  });
});
```