# Fabric js wrong shape when having negative height or width when setting rx and ry to nonzero value

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to draw rectangle with rounded corners but when setting negative width or height I'm getting a wrong shape like this [image: wrong behavior]

How to have the correct shape (the top left one in the gif) regardless of the start point and the draw direction?

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
    const roundedRect = new fabric.Rect( {
        top: e.pointer.y,
        left: e.pointer.x,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        rx: 10,
        ry: 10,
        fill: 'transparent',
        hasControls: false,
    });
    canvas.add(roundedRect);
    canvas.setActiveObject(roundedRect);
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', (e) => {
    const pointer = e.pointer;
    const activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    let height = pointer.y - activeObj.top;
    let width = pointer.x - activeObj.left;
    activeObj.set({ height: height, width: width});
    activeObj.setCoords();
});
```

Comment: Negative width and height values aren't supported in Fabric which is why you're getting unpredictable behavior. Use scaleX and scaleY instead which can be negative.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570497/how-to-maintain-rounded-corner-of-rect-when-scaling-in-fabric-js